# python url mapping syntax

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, url-mapping

I am writing a python program for google appengine using jinja2 as my template engine.  I would like to have a single handler for a multitude of posts and some of them having pretty different URLs but all having the same base.

Is is possible for me to have a URL handler like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/post/([.*]+)/([.*]+)/([.*]+)/([.*]+)', PostPage), ], debug=True)
```

And yet have it accept URLs that don't fill every one of those addtitions like having a URL:

/post/1234/some-title

If not is there some way that I can change it so that one handler can take URLs for many pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need (as parameters for the handler) the parts of the path that are after the /post/{param1} you can simple write `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/post/(.*)/.*', PostPage)` and the handler will except everything in the form of /post/{id}/.*

Comment: so it is giving me a error:  TypeError: get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) any idea why that is?

Comment: @clifgray if you have two params in your handler then the code should be: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/post/(.*)/(.*)/.*', PostPage)